# Cannot import redis in vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, redis, vite

When I simply import redis with vite:

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';
```

It fails with the following error (see with Cmd+F12):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js (socket.js:21:36)
    at __require (chunk-MS22ZBJX.js?v=39bad95c:27:50)
    at node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js (index.js:16:18)
    at __require (chunk-MS22ZBJX.js?v=39bad95c:27:50)
    at node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/index.js (index.js:14:18)
    at __require (chunk-MS22ZBJX.js?v=39bad95c:27:50)
    at node_modules/redis/dist/index.js (index.js:14:18)
    at __require (chunk-MS22ZBJX.js?v=39bad95c:27:50)
    at dep:redis:1:16
```

I build a stackblitz link as follows:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-5mtbrf?file=src/main.js